# GPPSignIn sharedInstance userID is always nil

Tags: ios, google-plus

In iOS, using the google + sdk and specifically following their [sign-in documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in)
I seem to be getting a nil userID, e.g. `[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] userID]` is `nil`

The first time I authorize the application I get a valid userId, but the second time I enter my application expecting to see a valid user id, it's nil again.
When I check `[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] trySilentAuthentication]` it returns true.

I'm following a very similar scenario to the one described in the [sample project](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started) .
What could be causing this?

Comment: Are you making sure that trySilentAuthentication is always called when the user returns to your application?

This: http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/06/common-issues-with-google-sign-in-on-ios.html describes how to handle that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I did these several steps to solve this problem:

1. Enable Google+ api in Google Developer Console
2. Set these properties to true

   ```
   googleSignin.scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"]
   googleSignin.shouldFetchGoogleUserID = true
   googleSignin.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = true
   googleSignin.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = true
   ```
3. Use `GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().userID` than `auth.userID` in `finishedWithAuth(auth: error:)`

Answer (score 0):

The Google user ID. It is only available if |shouldFetchGoogleUserID| is set and either |trySilentAuthentication| or |authenticate| has been completed successfully.you can use this.

```
    GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserID = YES;
    signIn.delegate = self;
    signIn.clientID = kClientId;
    signIn.scopes = @[kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin];

    signIn.actions = [NSArray  arrayWithObjects:@"http://schemas.google.com/ListenActivity",nil];
    [signIn authenticate];
```